# How to add multiple slashes to a single cell

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column with about 5k rows that I need to add slashes to. I need to add slashes to the first, second, and last space (" ") in the cell. Each cell has different lengths so there are different amounts of spaces between the second and last in each row.
Here's an example of some rows

```
NYLA D DURA FEMUR BCN LG
NULO D FZD GF BF 5oz
OMNI D BRTSH SLP LD GRN 4ft
OMNI D LIGHT S-HOOK
OMNI D SS BOWL 3qt
```

I need these converted to

```
NYLA/D/DURA FEMUR BCN/LG
NULO/D/FZD GF BF/5oz
OMNI/D/BRTSH SLP LD GRN/4ft
OMNI/D/LIGHT S-HOOK
OMNI/D/SS BOWL/3qt
```

I have tried using the substitute formula but that will only add one slash when I need to add 1-3. I'm not sure if nesting the substitute formula is possible in this scenario. If so, that should do it but I can't get it to work.

Comment: why is `OMNI D LIGHT S-HOOK` not `OMNI/D/LIGHT/S-HOOK`?

Comment: Hey Scott, sorry, that wasn't the best example to add since it was entered incorrectly to begin with. The last section after the last slash in the cell is the size or weight of the product so it should be OMNI/D/S-HOOK/LIGHT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested SUBSTITUTE is the way to go:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","/",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))," ","/",2)," ","/",1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Scott! Your formula works! I can't thank you enough! I figured it had to be a nested substitute, just didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Both formulas are similar and will do what you need.  Please mark the one you used as the correct formula but clicking the check mark by the answer you used.

Comment: One more question - what formula can I use if the first two spaces are already completed and I just need to fill in the last space? For example, ARIA/D/BLACK STARBURST SCRUNCHIE LG. Here I just need to replace the last space (right before the LG) with a slash. I know I can use =substitute(cell, " ","/",3) but am asking for a formula that would cover if there are more and/or less than three spaces after the first two spaces are already replaced with slashes.

Comment: Just use the inner(third) SUBSTITUTE `SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","/",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))`

Comment: Thanks, Scott. What about if I just need to fill the first two spaces with slashes and no where else in the cell?

Comment: Just replace the inner substitute with the cell address.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","/",LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","  "))-LEN(A1))," ","/",1)," ","/",1)
```

It replaces the last instance of " " followed by the first two instances.

This might however return an error if there are less than three " " in the string.

Comment: Thank you so much, Cubius! Your formula works! I do have some cells with less than three spaces (" ") in them, would I just use =substitute(cell, " ","/") for those?

Comment: I've just tested this formula again and it only throws an error if there is no space in the cell. Just add `IFERROR` to surround the formula to cath the error: `=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","/",LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","  "))-LEN(A1))," ","/",1)," ","/",1),A1)`